# How do I create an Excel Pivot connected to an Access DB that downloads only the queried data?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, olap

I have a table of around 60 columns and 400,000 rows and increasing. Our company laptops and MS Excel cannot handle this much data in RAM. So I decided to store the data in MS Access and link it to Excel.

However the pivot in Excel still downloads *all* the data into Excel, and *then* performs the filters and operations on the data. Which worked with lesser data, but with more data now has started giving memory errors. Also even though the data in the pivot might be only 50 cells, the file size is 30+ MBs...

**So is it possible to create a connection to Access in such a way that it downloads only the data that is queried, does the operations before hand and then sends the revised data to Excel?**

I saw this setup in my previous company (where the Excel pivot would only download what it needed). But it was querying an SQL DB as far as I remember. (Sadly couldn't learn more about it since the IT director was intent on being the only guy who knew core operations (He basically had the company's IT operations hostage in exchange for his job security))... But I digress.

I've tried searching for this on the internet for a few days, but it's a very specific problem that I can't find in Google :/

Any help or even pointers would be highly appreciated!

Edit: I'd just like to point out that I'm trying to create an OLAP connection for analysis, so the pivot would be changing fields. My understanding of how pivots work, was that when we select the fields in the pivot, excel would design a query (based on the select fields) and send it to the connection DB to retrieve the data requested. If this is not how it happens, how do I make something like this happen? Hope that elaborates.

Comment: If the query will always be the same, then I think @Renaud's answer is great. If you need to change the WHERE clause within Excel, you can do that in the connection and, using MS Query, you can even tie the paramaters to cells in a workbook: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-a-parameter-query-addf7cb7-ddf0-442f-a60c-cd7280e201bd?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Thanks @Doug, will look into MS Query. Also I thought when we change the fields of a pivot, excel sends a customized query (based on the fields and measures we selected) to the connection/DB so that it sends that specific data only, is this correct?

Comment: I don't think so. My understanding is that the PivotCache behind the scenes contains all the data. That's why @Renaud's answer should help; I believe it yields a smaller pivot cache.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you created a single massive table in Access to store all your data, so if you just link that table as the data source, Excel won't know which particular bit of data is relevant and will most probably have to go through all of it itself.

Instead, you can try a combination of different approaches:

- Create a query that pre-filters the data from Access and link that query to Excel.
  Use a `SQL` *Command Type* for your *Connection Properties* instead of a `Table`.
  Test that query in Access to make sure it runs well and is fast enough.
- Make sure that all important fields have indexes (fields you filter, fields you group by, any field that Excel has to go through to decide whether it should be included or not in the pivot, make sure that that field has a sensible index).
- Make sure that you have set a Primary Key in your table(s) in Access. Just use the default auto-increment `ID` if it's not already used.
- If all else fails, break down that huge table: it's not so much the amount of records that's too much it's more the high number of columns.
- If you use calculated fields in your pivot or filter data based on some criteria, consider adding columns to your table(s) in Access that contain pre-calculated data. For instance you could run a query from Access to update these additional fields or add some VBA to do that.

It should works pretty well though: to give you an idea, I've made some tests with Excel 2013 linked to a 250MB ACCDB containing 33 fields and 392498 rows (a log of stock operations): most operations on the pivot in Excel only take a fraction of a second, maybe a couple of seconds for the most data-intensive ones.

Another thing: Access has support [pivot tables and pivot charts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-views-in-a-desktop-database-83e524df-dfbd-456d-9dd0-0a48c1aa6752?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Maybe you don't need Excel if Access is enough. You can use the [Access Runtime 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910) or [2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358) (it's free) as a front-end on each machine that needs access to the data. Each [front-end can then be linked to the backend](http://www.opengatesw.net/ms-access-tutorials/Access-Articles/MSAccess-Deployment-Best-Practices.htm) database that holds the data on a network share. The tools are a bit more clunky than in Excel, but they work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the links. And Yes I did make a large table, though I did break it down into smaller tables, but eventually I relate them all into one large query. 
I'm basically trying to create an OLAP connection for BI analysis. And so a hard coded SQL query means I'd have to change the SQL query for every different view in the pivot? Also I just commented on Doug's point above, would highly appreciate your opinion. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, to avoid the creation of queries in the Access DB, is to use PowerPivot add-in in Excel, implementing there queries and normalizations.